# How to delete the latest revision on Cloud Run (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tags, google-cloud-run, traffic, revision

I'm trying to delete **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** but there is **the message "Latest revision cannot be deleted."** as shown below even though it doesn't have **any tags** and **0% Traffic** is set to it:

[image]

Is it impossible to delete **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's impossible to delete **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**. [**The documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/revisions#delete) says:

You cannot delete a revision if:

- it is able to receive traffic,
- it is the only revision of the service,
- it is the latest revision of the service. // Here

But, If you really want to delete **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"**, create **one more revision "editor-temp"** which becomes the latest while **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** becomes old as shown below, then now, you can delete **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

[image]